# JiBX Validation against a XSD Schema when unmarshalling to POJO

Tags: xml, xsd, unmarshalling, jibx

I cant find any examples on the web explaining how to validate XML against an existing XSD schema during the unmarshalling phase.

Currently I have which works fine:

```
IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory
    .getFactory(aClass.class);
IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();
    return (aClass) uctx.unmarshalDocument(new FileInputStream(
          fname), null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     throw new IOException(e);
    } catch (JiBXException e) {
     throw new IOException(e);
}
```

But where in this process can I tell Jibx to validate the XML against the schema before unmarshalling to the object?? Is it even possible with JiBX? I see examples using JaxB but none with JibX.

Answer (score 0):

JiBX does not support full-validation from scratch.

You have to create a javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory with an implementation which supports validation (such as the one supplied by Sun as part of their JDKs), then call setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, Boolean.TRUE) and create an actual parser with a createXMLStreamReader() call.

Once you have the validating parser for your input, you can use the org.jibx.runtime.impl.StAXReaderWrapper constructor to wrap this as an IXMLReader instance, which can then be set on your org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext unmarshalling context instance.

Weird, I known, you can find a request for making it easier here [JIBX-381](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JIBX-381)